# Filezilla denied - can't change permissions

Tags: filezilla

I own a server on Cloudways and log into the applications in FileZilla using my Master SFTP and SSH access credentials user name and password. However, I am not able to change the permissions on folders or files to 755 (or anything else) - I get "permission denied." All I'm trying to do is add some code to the .htaccess file but it won't overwrite back to the server. Any idea what's wrong?

1. Currently, the public_html folder is 755. The .htaccess file inside that is 644.
2. I am the owner and only user. I tried login in two ways: With the server name and pass (which shows me all the apps\sites) and with a specific app\site name and pass (which only shows me one site.) Both ways have the same issue.

Comment: What are the current permissions of the folder?

Comment: public_html folder is 755. The .htaccess file inside that is 644.

Comment: What user owns the .htaccess file and are you logging in as that user?

Comment: I am the owner and only user. I tried login in two ways: With the server name and pass (which shows me all the apps\sites) and with a specific app\site name and pass (which only shows me one site.) Both ways have the same issue.

Comment: I am not asking if you are or are not the owner.  I am asking what user owns the file and what user are you logging in as.  The file permissions won’t allow anyone except the owner to chnage the permissions in the file.  Please…[edit] your question with this necessary information

Comment: I think what I wrote was clear. I am the only user so I own the file. Hence, the server has one username\pass and the app\site has only one username\pass. I tried login in with both. If this doesn't answer your question, then I don't understand it.

Comment: I will ask my question another way.  If the file is owned by root are you logging in as root?

Comment: I know what root is on Linux but don't know how it's applied in Windows. This is from the Cloudways site: "The Cloudways Platform offers two kinds of credentials to give access to servers and applications. One is Master Credentials, and another is Application Credentials. Master credentials are the most powerful credentials on a Cloudways server. It gives you access to remotely access the server via SSH and SFTP and also to gain access to all applications within the entire server." http://bit.ly/root-cloudways

Comment: When you have provided an adequate amount of information about your problem your question will be in a state it can probably be answered.

Comment: If you tell me how to know if I'm logged in as root, I will check and tell you. All I see in Filezilla is Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/"...
Status: Listing directory /
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't have root permissions if you log in with Cloudways server credentials. You should log in with the app credentials and then you should get root access to make changes and upload files.

Comment: Thanks! You rock!

Answer (score 0):

I have The same issue after hacker attack. I’m trying to clean up but can’t change files in FileZilla or upload new?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).